# I sent data from database to a html file. But how can make this to no redirect to that page in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel-8

this is my controller. I want to return on this page 'home.checkout'.
`

```
public function checkoutpage(Request $request)
    {
        
         $n= $request->name;
         $g= $request->guests;
         $d= $request->duration;
         $t= $request->to;
         $date= $request->date;
         $data = $request->tid;
         booking::select('id')->where('name', $n)->first();

         
         
        
         
         return view ('home.paymentconfirm',compact('n','g','d','t','date','data'));

         return view('home.checkout');
```

`

this is my route

`Route::post('ticket-checkout',[bookingController::class,'checkoutpage'])->name('getmethod-checkout');`

my view file

`

```
<div class='wp'>Guests<h2>{{$g}}</h2></div>
      <div class='wp'>Type<h2>VIP</h2></div>
      <div class='wp'>Time<h2> {{$d}}</h2></div>
```

`

Now i want this checkout page appear before the paymentconfirm page.

Comment: You can't return two views from one action, that makes no sense. You need to first send the user to the checkout view, and then when they submit from the checkout view, you send them to the confirm page, using a different action

Comment: As @ADyson said you can not return twice in a method.  There can be only one. Think of it as the "last line" in that method. A proper IDE would flag that for you.

Comment: i want to checkout to be viewd first then payment confirm. but it appears payment confirm first because i send some data on that page. sorry for my bad English